# How can I display only the new state of the grid?

Tags: c#, text-based

I am making a console based snake game. I am able to move the snake using grids that show up successively on the console. I want to animate the snake using always the same grid.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        char[,] board = new char[17, 17];
        int count = 5;
        for (int i = 0; i <= 16;             {
            for (int j = 0; j <= 16; j++) 
            {
                board[i, j] = '.';
            }
        }
        while (count < 11)
        {
            board[8, count] = '*';
            board[8, count + 1] = '*';
            board[8, count + 2] = '*';
            board[8, count + 3] = '*';
            board[8, count + 4] = '*';
            board[8, count + 5] = '*';
            board[8, count + 6] = '*';

            for (int i = 0; i <= 16; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j <= 16; j++)
                {
                    Console.Write(board[i, j]);
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
            count++;
        }
    }
```

[image: snake]

Answer (score 2):

Assuming I understood your question correctly, simply call `Console.Clear()` before you draw your grid. This will clear the console of all text so when you draw your grid it will always be at the top.

Comment: I put the Console.Clear() function below the while loop and it only draws one grid but the last grid. But I want the snake to animate on the one grid.

Comment: @gamer67 Can you add a few pictures to show what you mean?

Comment: Put the clear() inside the while loop, at the beginning. If the animation is too fast, add a delay, or only move when a button is pressed

Comment: I put the clear in the bottom of the while loop and it works. I also put in a small delay.

Answer (score 0):

I have made some progress. I have got the snake to move to the right and to move down.

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        const int board_size = 17;
        char[,] board = new char[board_size, board_size];
        int horizontal = 5, vertical = 8, count = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < board_size; i++) 
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < board_size; j++) 
            {
                board[i, j] = '.';
            }
        }

        void draw_board()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < board_size; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < board_size; j++)
                {
                    Console.Write(board[i, j]);
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
        }

        while (count < 12)
        {
            if (count >= 0 && count < 6)
            {
                board[vertical, horizontal] = '*';
                board[vertical, horizontal + 1] = '*';
                board[vertical, horizontal + 2] = '*';
                board[vertical, horizontal + 3] = '*';
                board[vertical, horizontal + 4] = '*';
                board[vertical, horizontal + 5] = '*';
                board[vertical, horizontal + 6] = '*';

                draw_board();

                horizontal++;
            }

            if (count > 5 && count < 12)
            {
                board[vertical, horizontal] = '*';
                board[vertical+1, horizontal] = '*';
                board[vertical+2, horizontal] = '*';
                board[vertical+3, horizontal] = '*';
                board[vertical+4, horizontal] = '*';
                board[vertical+5, horizontal] = '*';
                board[vertical+6, horizontal] = '*';

                draw_board();

                vertical++;
            }

            count++;

            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
            Console.Clear();
        }
    }
```